# What does Magento coookie $secure variable do?

Tags: cookie

Could anyone be kind and explain what is the good practice for setting cookies in Magento with:

```
Mage::getModel(‘core/cookie’)->set($name, $value, $period, $path, $domain, $secure,$httponly);
```

I am especially interested what the `$secure` and `$httponly` do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento uses the default php [setcookie function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

> **secure** - Indicates that the cookie should only be transmitted over a
>   secure HTTPS connection from the client. When set to TRUE, the cookie
>   will only be set if a secure connection exists. On the server-side,
>   it's on the programmer to send this kind of cookie only on secure
>   connection (e.g. with respect to $_SERVER["HTTPS"]).
>
> **httponly** - When TRUE the cookie will be made accessible only through
>   the HTTP protocol. This means that the cookie won't be accessible by
>   scripting languages, such as JavaScript. It has been suggested that
>   this setting can effectively help to reduce identity theft through XSS
>   attacks (although it is not supported by all browsers), but that claim
>   is often disputed. Added in PHP 5.2.0. TRUE or FALSE

See  /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cookie.php

```
public function set($name, $value, $period = null, $path = null, $domain = null, $secure = null, $httponly = null)
{
    .....

    setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path, $domain, $secure, $httponly);

    return $this;
}
```